# Applying Zorn's lemma on a set of all sets.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $U$ be the set of all sets. Define a partial ordering on $U$ by inclusion: $A \leq B$
iff $A \subseteq B$ for $A, B \in U$.
Consider a chain $C$ of $U$ under this partial ordering:
$$
C : A_1 ≤ A_2 ≤ A_3 ≤ \cdots
$$
Define $B = \bigcup_{i\geq1}A_i$.
Clearly, $B \in U$ and it is an upper
bound of the chain $C$. Hence, Zorn’s Lemma implies that $U$ has a maximal element, say $M$.
The argument is clearly wrong since $M$ is not a maximal element:
$$
M \subsetneq \{M, \{M\}\} \in U.
$$
I can't identify which step in the argument is wrong and why.

Comment: Trivially, the set of all sets is a set, and it is the *maximum* of $U$. (Of course, there is no set of all sets, but even in a scenario that it does exist...)

Comment: $M$ is not actually a subset of the set $\{M, \{M\}\}$. I think you meant $M \cup \{M\}$. But it's only a strict subset of the latter if $M$ is not an element of itself (leading to Asaf's resolution).

Answer (score 8):

The first step is wrong: There is no set of all sets. Objects like this are not allowed in ZFC set theory in order to prevent contradictions like [Russel's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).

You could define a [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)) that contains all sets; however that class is no longer a set itself and cannot be treated as such.